# WPF image button

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am using two button in WPF i want to change their image ie image button on DIsable how to do it can any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

In WPF an Image button is simply a `Button` with its `Content` set to an image. So, if you want to change the image, you simply need to assign another image to the `Content` property of the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't change Image, since in WPF Button is just a button as @Daniel Hilgarth wrote. However you can make new style for button like - and apply it to your buttons. This might work like your requirements.

```
        <Style x:Key="BtnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />                
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <!--Image-->
                            <Image x:Name="BtnImage" Stretch="Fill" />
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!--Trigger for IsEnabled-->
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <!--Set the source of the image-->
                                <Setter TargetName="BtnImage" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/YouAppShortName;component/Image.png" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```